# Estou com erro de Apostrophe not preceded by

Tags: android, android-xml

Eu estou tentando fazer a internacionalização do meu app para o idioma inglês, mas acabo recebendo este erro

> Error:(10) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Please note, if you're on a device with android 6.0 above, you need the permissions that the app request the following screens to the proper functioning)

esse é meu string-en.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Lanterna Flash</string>
<string name="texto">Texto tester</string>

<string name="title_activity_fullscreen">FullscreenActivity</string>
<string name="dummy_button">Dummy Button</string>
<string name="dummy_content">DUMMY\nCONTENT</string>

<string name="tela1">Welcomes!</string>


<string name="tela2">Take advantage of our application, it is the flashlight for devices that have flash or the screen flash.</string>

<string name="tela3">Please note, if you're on a device with android 6.0 above, you need the permissions that the app request the following screens to the proper functioning</string>


<string name="avisoToast">Seu dispositivo não tem flash!</string>
```

e esse aqui é meu string.xml o que fica na pasta values:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Lanterna Flash</string>

<string name="texto">Texto tester</string>

    <string name="title_activity_fullscreen">FullscreenActivity</string>
<string name="dummy_button">Dummy Button</string>
<string name="dummy_content">DUMMY\nCONTENT</string>

<string name="tela1">Bem Vindo!</string>


<string name="tela2">Aproveite o nosso aplicativo, ele consiste na lanterna para aparelhos que tenham flash ou para o flash de tela.</string>

<string name="tela3">Atenção se você estiver em um aparelho com android 6.0 acima, será necessário das as permissões que o app solicitar nas telas a seguir para o devido funcionamento</string>


<string name="avisoToast">Seu dispositivo não tem flash!</string>
```

Não linguem para a tradução apenas to fazendo um teste, até então quando adiciono lá no string-en a tela 1 ele vai mais quando adiciono a tela 2 (os textos em inglês ele da esse erro) me ajudem quem puder eu agradeço...

Comment: Altere `if you're` por `if you\'re`

Comment: A mensagem de erro significa que você usou em alguma parte do texto um apóstrofo ( ' ) sem a sequência adequada de escape ( \' )

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado ramaral e Haroldo_OK, eu estava quebrando a cabeça com isso, coisa tão simples, e eu não achava nenhum exemplo na internet que me ajudasse, mas valeu :)

Comment: @ramaral você poderia postar uma resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Android apóstrofo(`'`) é um dos caracteres que, quando usados em [resources do tipo string](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling), têm de ser inseridos numa [sequência de escape](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequ%C3%AAncia_de_escape) ou, em alternativa, colocar toda a *string* entre aspas(`"`).

No seu caso o problema está na parte `you're` da *string* "tela3":

```
<string name="tela3">Please note, if you're on a device with android 6.0 above, you need the permissions that the app request the following screens to the proper functioning</string>
```

Coloque o carácter `\` antes do apóstrofo para criar a sequência de escape:

```
<string name="tela3">Please note, if you\'re on a device with android 6.0 above, you need the permissions that the app request the following screens to the proper functioning</string>
```

ou coloque toda a string entre aspas:

```
<string name="tela3">"Please note, if you're on a device with android 6.0 above, you need the permissions that the app request the following screens to the proper functioning"</string>
```

Outro carácter que necessita dos mesmo tratamento é as aspas que, neste caso, só pode ser resolvido recorrendo à sequência de escape.

```
<string name="exemplo">Isto é um "mau" exemplo</string>
<string name="exemplo">Isto é um \"bom\" exemplo</string>
```